# How to recover data from database using symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i need to display information of a product from my database but i have an

> error: Controller
>   "UserBundle\Controller\DefaultController::profileAction()" requires
>   that you provide a value for the "$id" argument (because there is no
>   default value or because there is a non optional argument after this
>   one).

This is the profileAction:

```
public function profileAction($id)
    {
      $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UserBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);
        if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
    );
        }
      return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:profile.html.twig', array('product' =>$product));
}
```

please someone help me.

Comment: the error is giving you all the information you need. "requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument" you need something like ?id=5 in your route/url.

Comment: this is my route:                                                                                     user_profile:
    path:     /profile/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:profile }
    methods: Get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a route like that :

```
_my_route:
    path: /my_path/{id}
    defaults: {controller: AcmeBundle:Default:profile}
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

Action in your controller :

```
public function profileAction($id)
{
  $product = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('UserBundle:Product')
    ->find($id);
    if (!$product) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException(
        'No product found for id '.$id
);
    }
  return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:profile.html.twig', array('product' =>$product));
```

And a link or something else in your view like that (Hope you use Twig):

```
<a  href="{{ path('_my_route', {'id':my_object.id}) }}"> Lorem ipsum </a>
```

It should be work.

**EDIT :**

For you search feature, i will do a route like that

```
_profile:
    path: /profile
    defaults: {_controller:AcmeBundle:Default:profile}
```

Controller :

```
public function profileAction(Request $request){

    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType());
    $products = null ;
    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $value = ($form['search']->getData());// change de 'search' according to your form
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() ;
        $product = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Product')->find($value) ;
    }
     if(!$product) throw $this->createNotFoundException('your message');

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:profile.html.twig',array(
        'product' => $product
    ));
}
```

And finally, your form in the view :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ path('_profile') }}">
//your code
</form>
```

Comment: after changement i have this error: No route found for "GET /profile" (from "http://localhost/OoucProject/web/app_dev.php/prod")

Comment: @meriem man : Do "php app/console debug:router" in your console : Do you find your route ?

Comment: but when i press my button:"rechercher" the route who appears in the url is  /profile, there is no the id who i had enter in my input.

Comment: in the view i called the route :                                                                       href="{{ path('user_profile', {'id':product.id}) }}"

Comment: Try a POST method without params (in your route etc); And in your controller your can do a    $form->handleRequest($request);
            $value = ($form['search']->getData()); and do your query. Do you see what i mean ?

Comment: no, it isn't so clear for me, please can you give me more details only about the controller.

Comment: Look my edit post just above, it's how i will do because I never use get form

Comment: no, it isn't work, i have anothe problem: when i click the button "produit" i get this error: Variable "product" does not exist in UserBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig at line 18. line 18 of the view recherche.html.twig:  <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ path('user_profile',{ 'id': product.id }) }}"  role="button">chercher</a>

Comment: Look in your controller linked to this view if it's the same spelling. You may be add a 's' in the  controller but not in the view. Its must be something like that. In the function render, you send the variable '$product' with the key 'product' ?

Comment: this is my action:   public function profileAction($id)
    {
      $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('UserBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);
        if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
    );
        }
      return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:profile.html.twig', array('product' => $product));
    }
}

Comment: routing.yml:                                                                                                          user_profile:
    path:     /profile/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:profile }
    requirements:
        id: \d+
    methods: Get                                                                                                    and my path in the view: href="{{ path('user_recherche') }}"

Comment: can you help me please, i didn't found a solution despite i searched a lot on the internet

Comment: I don't get it. In your view you call a path call 'user_recherche' without params but in your routing the path is called "user_profile" with params.

Comment: You have a view with a form and an input to search an user according to this id true ? The result of the search is display in the same view or in a different view ?

Comment: Ok, did you try with the POST form like i said in my post just above ?Like that no need to specify the id in the paramater of the route. Just have to recover the post value in your controller. But you have to take care of consistency of your route in the controller and the routing file

Comment: i try it but i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide $id as argument.

Change the return to something like that:

```
return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:profile.html.twig', ['product' => $product, 'id' => $id]);
```

Comment: but now i'm forced to enter the id of the product who i'm fetching in the url, if not i get this error:     No route found for "GET /profile" (from "http://localhost/OoucProject/web/app_dev.php/prod")

Comment: You also could change the {{ path }} section in your template and and generate the path ``<a  href="{{ path('profile_show', {'id':product.id}) }}">Profile</a>``

Comment: what do you mean by  change the {{ path }} section in your template???      my route is: href="{{ path('user_profile',{ 'id': product.id }) }}"                       what i schould change else???

Comment: Did the product have an id? Maybe this could be your problem. Remove the link and check with ``{{ dump(product.id) }}``. Maybe some of your product do not have an id. so The profile_show rout will be generated with Parameter "?id=NULL".

Comment: Action in controller: public function profileAction(Request $request){ $form= $this->createForm(new SearchType());                         $product= null;
if ($request->isMethod('Post')){
$form->handleRequest($request);
         
 $product= ($form['id']->getData());
  $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() ;
   $product= $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Product')->find($id);
          }
      if(!$product) throw $this->createNotFoundException ('ce produit n existe pas' .$id);
         return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:profile.html.twig', array('product'=> $product
              ));
    }

Comment: the route: user_profile:
    path:     /profile
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:profile }

Comment: the view: <form method="post" action= "{{ path('user_profile') }}" >
            <button type="submit">chercher</button>
        </form>

Comment: somebody help me please

Comment: In your controller action: "Undefined parameter $id"

Answer (score 0):

Well i think that here $id become null and it causes error because $id is used to fetch data from your db, so set default value for $id check $id will never become null or empty. All the best.